# wired connection stopped working

Tags: networking, ethernet, netplan, 23.10

On my desktop (Ubuntu 23.10 only) I have both ethernet (Intel 211) and wireless.  The ethernet connection stopped working; I can't reach the Deco router.  The wireless connection works ok.  The ethernet connection shows up fine under lshw and rebooting, replacing cables, resetting router did not revive it and neither did various online suggestions (disabling ipv6, etc).  Any suggestions on how I can debug this problem?

Thanks!!!!

```
 *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:43:00.0
       logical name: enp67s0
       version: 03
       serial: b4:2e:99:ad:d4:21
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=6.5.0-17-generic duplex=full firmware=0. 6-1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:50 memory:e6500000-e651ffff ioport:9000(size=32) memory:e6520000-e6523fff
```

relevant lines of ip a

```
2: enp67s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:2e:99:ad:d4:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

ip r is empty

relevant lines of ip l

```
2: enp67s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:2e:99:ad:d4:21 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

relevant lines of journalctl -u NetworkManager:

```
Feb 20 12:40:05 poppyrose NetworkManager[3698]: <warn>  [1708450805.9081] device (enp67s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
Feb 20 12:40:05 poppyrose NetworkManager[3698]: <info>  [1708450805.9083] device (enp67s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 20 12:40:05 poppyrose NetworkManager[3698]: <info>  [1708450805.9119] dhcp4 (enp67s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Feb 20 12:40:05 poppyrose NetworkManager[3698]: <info>  [1708450805.9119] dhcp4 (enp67s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 20 12:40:05 poppyrose NetworkManager[3698]: <info>  [1708450805.9119] dhcp4 (enp67s0): state changed no lease
Feb 20 12:40:05 poppyrose NetworkManager[3698]: <info>  [1708450805.9120] dhcp6 (enp67s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Feb 20 12:40:05 poppyrose NetworkManager[3698]: <info>  [1708450805.9121] dhcp6 (enp67s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 20 12:40:05 poppyrose NetworkManager[3698]: <info>  [1708450805.9121] dhcp6 (enp67s0): state changed no lease
Feb 20 12:40:05 poppyrose NetworkManager[3698]: <info>  [1708450805.9131] manager: startup complete
Feb 20 12:40:43 poppyrose NetworkManager[3698]: <info>  [1708450843.6498] device (enp67s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (156c014f-20d7-3c74-ace4-ef1db1570dab)
Feb 20 12:40:43 poppyrose NetworkManager[3698]: <info>  [1708450843.6500] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="156c014f-20d7-3c74-ace4-ef1db1570dab" name="Wired connection 1" pid=6089 uid=1000 result="success"
Feb 20 12:40:43 poppyrose NetworkManager[3698]: <info>  [1708450843.6501] device (enp67s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 20 12:40:43 poppyrose NetworkManager[3698]: <info>  [1708450843.6503] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Feb 20 12:40:43 poppyrose NetworkManager[3698]: <info>  [1708450843.6505] device (enp67s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 20 12:40:43 poppyrose NetworkManager[3698]: <info>  [1708450843.6515] device (enp67s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 20 12:40:43 poppyrose NetworkManager[3698]: <info>  [1708450843.6528] dhcp4 (enp67s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 20 12:40:49 poppyrose NetworkManager[3698]: <info>  [1708450849.2189] dhcp6 (enp67s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Feb 20 12:40:49 poppyrose NetworkManager[3698]: <info>  [1708450849.2192] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (enp67s0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
```

output of `nmcli connection show Wired\ connection\ 1` after emptying directory and rebooting:

```
connection.id:                          Wired connection 1
connection.uuid:                        156c014f-20d7-3c74-ace4-ef1db1570dab
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.type:                        802-3-ethernet
connection.interface-name:              enp67s0
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.autoconnect-priority:        -999
connection.autoconnect-retries:         -1 (default)
connection.multi-connect:               0 (default)
connection.auth-retries:                -1
connection.timestamp:                   0
connection.permissions:                 --
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:                 --
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        default
connection.mdns:                        -1 (default)
connection.llmnr:                       -1 (default)
connection.dns-over-tls:                -1 (default)
connection.mptcp-flags:                 0x0 (default)
connection.wait-device-timeout:         -1
connection.wait-activation-delay:       -1
802-3-ethernet.port:                    --
802-3-ethernet.speed:                   0
802-3-ethernet.duplex:                  --
802-3-ethernet.auto-negotiate:          no
802-3-ethernet.mac-address:             --
802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address:      --
802-3-ethernet.generate-mac-address-mask:--
802-3-ethernet.mac-address-blacklist:   --
802-3-ethernet.mtu:                     auto
802-3-ethernet.s390-subchannels:        --
802-3-ethernet.s390-nettype:            --
802-3-ethernet.s390-options:            --
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan:             default
802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan-password:    --
802-3-ethernet.accept-all-mac-addresses:-1 (default)
ipv4.method:                            auto
ipv4.dns:                               --
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       --
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         --
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.routing-rules:                     --
ipv4.replace-local-rule:                -1 (default)
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.required-timeout:                  -1 (default)
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-vendor-class-identifier:      --
ipv4.link-local:                        0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-reject-servers:               --
ipv4.auto-route-ext-gw:                 -1 (default)
ipv6.method:                            auto
ipv6.dns:                               --
ipv6.dns-search:                        --
ipv6.dns-options:                       --
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:                         --
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            --
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv6.routing-rules:                     --
ipv6.replace-local-rule:                -1 (default)
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.required-timeout:                  -1 (default)
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     default
ipv6.ra-timeout:                        0 (default)
ipv6.mtu:                               auto
ipv6.dhcp-pd-hint:                      --
ipv6.dhcp-duid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-iaid:                         --
ipv6.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv6.dhcp-hostname-flags:               0x0 (none)
ipv6.auto-route-ext-gw:                 -1 (default)
ipv6.token:                             --
proxy.method:                           none
proxy.browser-only:                     no
proxy.pac-url:                          --
proxy.pac-script:                       --
GENERAL.NAME:                           Wired connection 1
GENERAL.UUID:                           156c014f-20d7-3c74-ace4-ef1db1570dab
GENERAL.DEVICES:                        enp67s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.STATE:                          activating
GENERAL.DEFAULT:                        no
GENERAL.DEFAULT6:                       yes
GENERAL.SPEC-OBJECT:                    --
GENERAL.VPN:                            no
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/7
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2
GENERAL.ZONE:                           --
GENERAL.MASTER-PATH:                    --
```

Comment: Please [edit] with `ip a ; ip r ; ip l` and the relevant lines in `journalctl -u NetworkManager` . Have you also tried deleting the Ethernet profile and letting it regenerate on the next boot?

Comment: have done, thanks

Comment: and this is after deleting the ethernet profile and letting it regenerate

Comment: This is similar to https://askubuntu.com/q/1504097/1004020 . Try `sudo rm /etc/netplan/*` , reboot, then post the output of `nmcli connection show Wired\ connection\ 1`

Comment: @DanielT have done; also tried your suggestion in the post you linked

Comment: What's `NetworkManager --print-config` ? Your hardware and profiles look fine. Do you see anything unusual in Wireshark? If nothing works, you could try setting a static IP if that's an option.

Comment: Had tried replugging and replacing all the cables before, static ip address, everything.   Just tried plugging the ethernet cable to a different port on the router and that worked.  No idea what made the difference: has been the old way for at least a year.  Thanks for your help @DanielT

Comment: It might have had something to do with either MAC randomization, connectivitycheck servers, or the router DHCP getting confused by that port (restarted the router might have been able to help)

Comment: Thanks @DanielT.  I had restarted the router, but that didn't help.  I'm baffled why it works now.